# C# implement function about way synchronization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, inverse

I did this:

```
businessCRM.Description = 
    string.Format("{0}\n" +
             "Name: {1}\n" +
             "Street: {2}\n " +
             "Number: {3}\n" +
             "floor: {4}\n" +
      business.Name,
      business.Address.Street,
      business.Address.Number,
      business.Address.floor,
);
```

And I would like to do the same but **inversely** in other method something like this to do way synchronization (round trip):

```
business.Address.Street = businessCRM.Description;
business.Address.Number = businessCRM.Description;
business.Address.floor = businessCRM.Description;
```

But I don't know if this is completely correct, any idea?

Comment: String.format is used completely wrong. Where is your format? What's more, you cannout simply "invere" foramtted string. You need to pare it firstly.

Comment: In first place your `string.Format` is wrong as first parameter is format string. Second: Why do you merge it if you need to access it individually?

Comment: I updated code, you can see the code that I have now.

Comment: Why you need to parse it from description?

Comment: Can your description perhaps contain something like json? then it would be trivial to do. The word you are looking for here is probably "serialization", btw - not "synchronization"

Comment: Yes, I use JSON too. The first code I can't modify it

Answer (score 0):

The real solution would be to put an additional `Address` member in your `businessCRM` class, so you can store the data *and* the description and don't need to extract the data from the description later. Parsing it will only lead to problems.

Comment: Can you put an example please?

Comment: @user1911 An example is not possible without seeing your code. You never gave the class declaration of whatever businessCRM is. Post more code and I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull it apart into a dictionary using something like the below; note I had to special-case the first line (has no prefix), and it won't work well if your data includes newlines internally in the values:

```
var parts = new Dictionary<string, string>(
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
string firstLine;
using(var reader = new StringReader(description))
{
    string line;
    firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
    var splitBy = new[] { ':' };
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var pair = line.Split(splitBy, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (pair.Length == 2) parts[pair[0].Trim()] = pair[1].Trim();
    }
}
string tmp;

string name, street, number, floor; // in your case, you could assign to
                                    // the properties directly
name = parts.TryGetValue("Name", out tmp) ? tmp : "";
street = parts.TryGetValue("Street", out tmp) ? tmp : "";
number = parts.TryGetValue("Number", out tmp) ? tmp : "";
floor = parts.TryGetValue("floor", out tmp) ? tmp : "";
```

Comment: BTW: `// in your case, you could assign to the properties directly`- its wrong - cannot use `out` with object properties, I mean: `myMethod("Name", out myObj.Name)` - causes compile time error.

Comment: @pwas you misunderstand; I mean "in place of the variables", i.e. `business.Address.Street = parts.TryGetValue("Street", out tmp) ? tmp : "";` etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all see  @Marc Gravell comment under question - it would be much easer to handle "deserialization". 
If not, here is solution.

1. my code may be slow - you need to cache reflection info (like property info collection)
2. there is no error handling and checking (ex. for nullity - do it manually ;))
3. Code assumes that input is always proper input (f.e. new line char inside value), format etc.

Code:

```
var addressType = business.Address.GetType();

foreach (var line in businessCRM.Description
                                .Split(new[] { "\n", Environment.NewLine },
                                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var propSelectorIndex = line.IndexOf(":");
    if (propSelectorIndex == -1) continue;

    var propName = line.Subtring(0, propSelectorIndex);
    var propInfo = addressType.GetProperties(BindigsFlag.Public 
                                                      | BindigsFlag.Instance)
                              .FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == propName);

    if (propInfo == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var newPropValue = line.Substring(propSelectorIndex + 2); 
                 // + 2 to omit : char and additional space
    propInfo.SetValue(business.Address, newPropValue, null);
}
```